# How to remove element from array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, random

So I'm trying to randomly select an element from a string, copy that element into another array, and then delete the randomly selected element from the original string.

However, I can't seem to get my code to do this properly. I tried slicing and popping the original string but neither technique seems to work, and I don't know why. If anyone could help, I would be very appreciative.

```
for (var i=0; i < inputword.length; i++)
{
    letter = inputword[Math.floor(Math.random() * inputword.length)];
    anagram[i]=letter;
    inputword.slice(letter,1);
}

$("label").text(anagram);
```

Comment: If you had just copy/pasted the title of your question into google and clicked the first link, you wouldn't have had to do all of that typing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-specific-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way in your code would be

```
inputword = inputword.slice(letter,1);
```

Because slice() returns a new Array.

Alternately you can use splice() which modifies the existing array.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing returns a shallow copy of the original array, [it does not alter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Description) the original array. As [Zaphyk states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839000/5190261) you'd want to assign the return of slice to "inputword" to have the removal persist to your original array.

Be careful with splice because it acts on the original array but [*returns* the removed elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Returns)!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i < inputword.length; i++)
{
  letter = inputword[Math.floor(Math.random() * inputword.length)];
  anagram[i]=letter;

  //You need to reassign your sliced word
  inputword = inputword.slice(letter,1);
}
$("label").text(anagram);
```